# "of which ... " vs "which ... of"

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is it possible to make the first sentence in a different way like the second one?

1. "The/That" modifies the noun so as to mean "the noun ***of
   which*** we were aware"
2. "The/That" modifies the noun so as to mean "the noun ***which***
   we were aware ***of***"

Are there any differences in meaning even in nuance?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct; you can use the preposition "of" either before "which" or at the end of the sentence, without any difference in meaning i.e:

......of which we were aware.

......which we were aware of.

......that we were aware of.

In everyday English, we usually use the preposition at the end of the sentence.  However, its use before "which" is more formal.

Further, it's more idiomatic to use "that" in place of "which" when we use the preposition at the end of the sentence. The sentence will also be correct if you drop which/that.

Comment: is it correct to use ''that'' with '' of ''? (of that) 

1)''The/that '' modifies the noun so as to mean ''the noun of that we were aware''

Comment: No, @ullas84, it's not grammatical to use the subordinator _that_ after a preposition. Normally the subordinator can freely replace the relative pronoun _which_ If you want to put the preposition before it, you need the relative pronoun.